# How do I use CSS to scale the font to the viewport while maintaining a two-column layout?

Tags: html, css, viewport, font-size

I have HTML and CSS code like this:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <span class="alignleft">First event, including a few words of description</span>
        <span class="alignright">Date of first event</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#main {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 50em;
    padding: 1.5em;
}

span.alignleft {
    float: left;
    width:80%;
    text-align:left;
}

span.alignright {
    float: left;
    width:20%;
    text-align:right;
}
```

On a large window/viewport, this produces text in a two-column layout like this (which is what I want):

[image: Text that isn't wrapped]

On a smaller window/viewport, e.g. a mobile browser, this produces text like this:

[image: Wrapped text]

There isn't a lot of text here, so I'd like the font to scale according to the viewport instead of wrapping, as much as possible (and this should be possible on most viewports because, again, there isn't a lot of text here).

However, if I add `font-size:2vw` elements to the CSS, e.g.

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 50em;
  padding: 1.5em;
}

span.alignleft {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 8vw;
}

span.alignright {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <span class="alignleft">First event, including a few words of description</span>
    <span class="alignright">Date of first event</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This kills the two-column layout and the rest of the formatting. How do I fix this?

Comment: why do you have `8vw` for the left column?  also, I would suggest presenting your code in a snippet instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @billynoah I'm not sure what you mean. None of the *code* is presented as a screenshot. Only the output is included as a screenshot.

Comment: there is a screenshot directly above the words "How do I fix this" - instead of showing us a screenshot, just add a snippet so we can see how the markup renders in a browser, not in an image.

Comment: Have you thought of doing `media queries` and adjusting the layout itself to work with different browser sizes? Like changing the widths, etc..

Comment: @billynoah Oh, I see what you mean. I didn't realize snippets could emulate different viewports/browsers, but I'll try to get that to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `fw` unit for `font-size` as you did, but you simply have to use smaller values. Start with `font-size: 0.5vw` and change the value slowly trying different values to get the desired result.

Keep in mind: One `vw` is one percent of the screen width, so for a 1000px wide screen, 8vw means 80px fontsize!

Answer (score 2):

You can add your desired `font-size:2vw` to scale with viewport along with a couple of other rules:

- Setting the wrapper and spans to render as table and cells
- Setting `white-space` on the spans to `nowrap`

This seems to do what you want but renders a bit odd on a large viewport.  An improved approach would probably be to use at least one media query and to set the dynamic font size only on smaller screens.

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 50em;
  padding: 1.5em;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main>div.row {
  display: table-row;
}

span.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

span.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

span.alignleft,
span.alignright {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main {
    padding: .5em;
  }
  span.alignleft,
  span.alignright {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: calc(6px + 1.5vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="alignleft">First event, including a few words of description</span>
      <span class="alignright">Date of first event</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="alignleft">First event, including a few words of description</span>
      <span class="alignright">Date of first event</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: +1 This looks like it's close to what I'm trying to do, thank you. I should have included a better example in my initial question, but how does this handle multiple lines of text? I can't put stack snippets in comments, but [in a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqg8m3kb/), it dumps everything on one line.

Comment: @MichaelA - I've updated my answer with (1) a demonstration of how to create rows in a pseudo table layout like this and (2) an improved dynamic font size which prevents to font from becoming completely unreadable at smaller viewport sizes.  I think this is still slightly problematic but should at least get you some ideas to play with.